# What's this "Album artist" tag iTunes uses? Any way to set it using java?

Tags: java, mp3, id3

iTunes uses an [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) tag called *"Album Artist"*, and for one album to be actually grouped as an album in iTunes, both the Album Name and Album Artist must be the same.

As far as I'm concerned, Album Artist isn't an official [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) tag, and from the [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) libraries I've seen so far, none supported "Album Artist".

[image: Preview]

Does anyone know more about this strange tag, and how to set it in java (or with any command line utility).

Comment: Windows. But I'd rather have a java (cross-platform) utility instead of a command line tool

Comment: I believe "album artist" is referred to as "Band/Orchestra/Accompaniment" in id3v2.4 (see [here](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames) - TPE2)

Comment: My experience of it (at least wrt foobar2000) is that an album should be grouped by "album artist" as opposed to "artist" because there could be multiple contributing artist to an album. I believe a very common approach is for each track to have its own artist (if applicable) and then the entire album to have the same "album artist". MP3Tag is a pretty powerful utility if you want greater control over your tags.

Comment: As far as Java is concerned, the first [library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) I came across had TPE2 support so I'm guessing you can find numerous libraries to do this for you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The commenters above are correct, `TPE2` ("Band/Orchestra/Accompaniment") is the ID3 tag which is usually repurposed for this. I know that at least iTunes, Windows Media Player, J River Media Center, and XBMC all use this tag, because I use it extensively in my own music collection and all of those applications have supported it seamlessly.

To edit this tag:

**Graphically**: you really can't go wrong with [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/), the only graphical editor (Windows in this case, but works fine under Wine) I've used which handles multiple files really well (leaves values alone unless you specifically change them), lets you customise which fields you have (and how they map to ID3 or FLAC tags, etc), and has other nice stuff like handling multiple image types for the `APIC` tag (front cover, back cover, disc image, band photo) cleanly, etc. Highly recommended.

**From the command line**: the [id3v2](http://id3v2.sourceforge.net/) command-line tool works a treat in this case:

```
$ id3v2 -l foo.mp3 
[...]
id3v2 tag info for foo.mp3:
TFLT (File type): MPG/3
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): Because Of The Blood (Single Version)
TPE1 (Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)): Sin Fang
TPE2 (Band/orchestra/accompaniment): Sin Fang
[...]

$ id3v2 --TPE2 "Spice Girls" foo.mp3

$ id3v2 -l foo.mp3 | grep TPE2
TPE2 (Band/orchestra/accompaniment): Spice Girls
```

(this tool is available by default in the Ubuntu repos, `sudo apt-get install id3v2`)

**From Java:**

Use something like the [javamusictag](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) project. I haven't used this in a while but something like:

```
MP3File file = new MP3File(new java.io.File("foo.mp3"));
((FrameBodyTPE2) file.getID3v2Tag().getFrame("TPE2").getBody()).setText("Backstreet Boys");
file.save();
```

is pretty close (or at least, close enough to get you started).

Comment: I highly appreciate this! Very good example code as well! You really deserve my 50 rep points :P

Comment: +1 for the right answer and for using the Backstreet Boys in your example

Comment: Such a shame standard programs use TPE2 to Album Artist, since it had quite a different purpose on its design. And since iTunes had used it, it would be really hard to undo the damge...

Comment: iTunes does a bunch of questionable stuff though. Like their custom `TCMP` tag for "part of a compilation," which is not supported by many other tools. (Although that's a big thing missing from id3v2 as well.)