# How do I set "Album Artist" of a song programmatically or through command line (linux)

Tags: linux, perl, audio, command-line, metadata

There are various command line tools available for editing metadata of audio files. But none of them can edit "Album artist" tag of the audio file. Is there any command line tool or perl module to do the same ? Thanks

Comment: What kind of tag are you updating?  ID3?  Tablib can write to many.

Comment: Yes, it is ID3V2 (ID3v2.3) . Third tag mentioned here - http://help.mp3tag.de/main_tags.html .

Comment: Found the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922622/whats-this-album-artist-tag-itunes-uses-any-way-to-set-it-using-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MP3::Tag support it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MP3::Tag;

$mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($filename);
$mp3->new_tag("ID3v2");
$mp3->{ID3v2}->add_frame("TALB", "Album title");
$mp3->{ID3v2}->add_frame("TPE2", "Album artist");
$mp3->{ID3v2}->write_tag;
$mp3->close();
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MP3::Tag;

$mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($filename);
$mp3->select_id3v2_frame_by_descr('TPE2', 'album artist'); # Edit in memory
$mp3->update_tags(); # commit
$mp3->close();
```

Comment: Just for info of new users - First code will create a new ID3V2 tag (so it might delete the previous tag in the file) and the second code will just update frame of an existing ID3V2 tag.

Answer (score 5):

`mid3v2` comes with the [mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/) library and is the best command-line tool for this purpose that I know of. When called with the `-f` argument, the `TPE2` tag is listed as supported.

Comment: Specifically, setting the album artist can be done with, e.g. `mid3v2 --TPE2 "Fiona Ann Artist" *.mp3`. `mid3v2` has no shorthand for `TPE2`, so using the long option.