# Remove "Album Artist" ID3 Tag with bash?

Tags: bash, scripting, tags, id3

Recently Amarok2 started taking care about that mysterious Tag "Album Artist" which ruined my collection because some files have different Artist and Album Artist tag (sometimes a typo, or a capital letter or whatever).
I just want to get rid off of that tag (or even better, deleting every tag BUT the important ones: Artist, Album, Title, Genre, Year, Track number)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I think it's still worth giving what I think is a good answer, so that people who may find this question in the future will easily be able to solve their problem.

1. install eyeD3 (this is the only part that wouldn't go in your script, obviously).

> `sudo apt-get install eyeD3`

2. CD to the directory that you have your target files in.
3. Use this:

> `eyeD3 --remove-all *.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to invoke some tool that allows you to edit the tags. For example, using `id3v2` the following will delete the mentioned tag from all files with extension `mp3` under the current directory:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3' -exec id3v2 --TPE2 "" {} \;
```

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922622/whats-this-album-artist-tag-itunes-uses-any-way-to-set-it-using-java) about `TPE2`)
This tool doesn't support deleting tags except a certain set. If you know what tags you want to delete, you can list them with empty string. Otherwise, you should probably find a better tool, or work around by querying the tags that should be kept then clearing all tags and finally adding the saved tags back.