# How to change the title of a mp3 in Java

Tags: java, file

i am trying to change the title of mp3 i did a lot of search,([Reading Windows file summary properties (title, subject, author) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096973/reading-windows-file-summary-properties-title-subject-author-in-java))  was the closest to what i want still i couldnt figure out how to employ the answer.

Comment: That has nothing to do with windows file summary, and everything to do with the mp3 file format, which stores information such as the title.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922622/whats-this-album-artist-tag-itunes-uses-any-way-to-set-it-using-java (Not an exact duplicate, because it changes the *album*. However, it contains a link to the full list of tags.)

Answer (score 3):

The title that is shown in the media player application is in a meta data format that is special for mp3 files, called [ID3 tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3). It is not a file system property.

There are a libraries that can read and write those tags. I have found a few but have no idea how well they work.

- https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic
- http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/